# Prevent operational risk with SQL-dependent architecture

Tags: mysql, sql

I am currently working on a very critical tool, which has a strong dependency to a MySQL database. 
This particularly means that if the SQL server goes down some day, all users won't be able to use the application, since it is retrieving their configuration stored in database and launches components defined in DB, and a configuration is absolutely required for the tool to be launched.

I was therefore wondering what were my options to limit this risk, ie. make the application functional even if the database is down. Should I define a fallback database for example?
It is the first time I work with such a critical aspect and I haven't been introduced to this kind of risk-management.

Any insights would be welcome

Comment: Is the tool something that lots of people will have installed, or is it a web app?

Comment: Have a look in the high availability chapter of the documentation : http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/ha-overview.html

Comment: @Steve Mayne: It is a tool everybody has already installed locally, I am now working on its availability. The tool will always retrieve the user config from the database and is used to allow administrators to update user configs at anytime
@Julio Guerra : thanks for the article, I've already read it though, but since it just focuses on theoretical aspects I want to know more about common used methods :)

Comment: If you're just using the database to dish out the current config - then caching it locally in the app doesn't seem like a bad idea.  As long as the consequence of using 'old' config isn't extreme.  You could record a timestamp with your local cached config, so you can stop it working if the config goes too far out of date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not the app's responsibility to implement fail-safe SQL backend. The app should check wheter the SQL server is running, and if not, it may retry the last SQL statement for a while, and print out a sad message in red if failed. If there are more SQL servers (hotswap or something), the app may switch automatically between them. That's the maximum an app would do in this topic.

I think there are lotsa solutions and ideas for setting up a fail-safe SQL server or farm, but it's out of scope (I mean programming).

Comment: This is what I was considering: saving last config loaded somewhere locally and load it if SQL fails... If as you said it is the maximum an app could do, I think I'll aim at "just" saving it locally!